# projectR: How to add a plot in a new window (Linux)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am completely new to projectR but I have tried to find a way to simply add a new graphical frame (window) to plot  another plot but at the same time keep my exising plot in the other window. SOmething like just do "figure" in matlab.
I am running on Linux

Comment: If you're lazy like me, then `x11()` can also work, depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to open a new device -

`dev.new()` - will open the device.

Then the plot you will create will be on this device.